# How can I get 2 variables from each line of a text file?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a text file with 2 sets of names separated by a specific character.
I want to write a batch file that will set anything before that character to one variable and anything after it to another.
Example:

```
%%a=NCIS Los Angeles, %%b=NCIS.Los.Angeles
```

Contents of Text File

```
NCIS Los Angeles|NCIS.Los.Angeles  
New Girl|New.Girl   
Once Upon a Time|Once.Upon.a.Time   
Revenge|Revenge   
Rizzoli and Isles|Rizzoli.and.Isles
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=|" %%a in (textfile.txt) do (
  echo %%a, %%b
  rem do something useful with the variables
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=|" %%a in ('type "yourtextfile.txt"') do (
  set NAME1=%%a
  set NAME2=%%b
  echo NAME1 is !NAME1!
  echo NAME2 is !NAME2!
)
endlocal
```